# Uploading file using Paramiko in Python seemingly works, but the file cannot be found on the server

Tags: python, file, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I am new to Python and sorry for my bad english.
I'm trying to save a file "toto.txt" from my HDD "d:" to my Synology NAS.
So I'll use paramiko for this, here is the code :

```
import paramiko
import os

ip_address = "my nas ip"
username = "my username"
password = "mypass"
utilisateur = os.getenv("USERNAME") // to get Windows username
remote_path = f"{utilisateur}/test.txt" // the file downloaded
local_path = "d:/toto.txt" //the file stored on my pc

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip_address,username=username,password=password)
print("Connexion OK >", ip_address)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(f'mkdir {utilisateur}') //creating folder for the 
user
sftp = ssh_client.open_sftp()
sftp.put(local_path,remote_path) // trying to send the file
sftp.close()
ssh_client.close()
```

i am not getting error but nothing is happening.
The folder is successful created but no file is sending in it.
Have someone an idea?
thanks a lot

Comment: I am very curious to hear how you got Paramiko installed in the first place, and what DSM version is running on your NAS? Let me know and I will replicate your case to be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

If Paramiko does not throw any error, the upload was successful. The file just possibly ended in different location than you wanted/than you look to.

At least for a test, if not permanently, try an absolute absolute path. Make no guesses, use the *exact* path you see in your GUI SFTP client.

---

Another possibility is that the server automatically processes the uploaded file somehow and moves it away.